# regex for String contains comma semicolon and Carriage return

Tags: regex, vb.net

I need to check if an input string contains a semicolon or a comma or carriage return or all of them

```
Dim Input As String = "1298-673-4192,A08Z-931-468A;" 
Dim pattern as string ="^[a-zA-Z0-9 \r , ; ]*$"
Dim regex As New Regex(pattern)
regex.Ismatch(Input)
```

I get false for it even though the string contains a comma a semicolon and a carriage return are present

Comment: `if (Input.IndexOfAny(new []{';', ',', '\r'}) >= 0)` perhaps.

Comment: with `^$` it checks the entire string. What you wrote will only return true when the entire string is one of the characters.

Comment: Your regex is checking that your string contains only those characters in its pattern, because of the start-of-string and end-of-string anchors.  Your source text has hyphens, which don't match your pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
Dim Input As String = "1298-673-4192,A08Z-931-468A;" 
Dim pattern as string ="[\r,;]+"
Dim regex As New Regex(pattern)
regex.Ismatch(Input)
```

I removed `^` and `$` because that checks the entire string (`^` means begin of string while `$` means end).

I changed `*` to `+` because `*` checks for 0 or more while `+` checks for 1 or more.

I removed the spaces because they were not necessary.

I removed the `a-zA-Z0-9` because that will also match all alphanumeric characters.

[Before](http://regexr.com/3c08h) (With string begin/end characters, spaces, alphanumerical and `*`).

[After](http://regexr.com/3c08t) (Without all the stuff that causes it to break).